# How do I form the following POST multipart/form-data request

Tags: java, rest, post, groovy, multipartform-data

I have the following POST-acceptable request template

[The request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUuRb.png)

However, I've encoutered a few problems implementing it using groovy.

My code is below:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
import groovyx.net.http.*
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

def baseURL = 'someBaseURL';
def URLToGo = baseURL + '/api/postJsonAndImage';
def httpRequest = new HTTPBuilder(URLToGo);
def authToken = 'AR-JWT ' + 'MYJWTTOKEN'

def headers = ['Authorization' : authToken];  
httpRequest.setHeaders(headers);
httpRequest.setContentType('multipart/form-data; boundary=W3NByNRZZYy4ALu6xeZzvWXU3NVmYUxoRB');

httpRequest.request(Method.POST) 
{
    req ->

    MultipartEntity multiPartContent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    multiPartContent.addPart('JSON', new StringBody('{"values":{"Incident Number":"INC000036078321","Work Log Type":"General Information","Description":"test","z2AF Work Log01":"book.xlsx"}}', ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    multiPartContent.addPart('base64', new StringBody('UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDk5p4srgEAALIIAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...')); // I have trimmed base64 for simplicity
    req.setEntity(multiPartContent);

}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I have a few questions:

1. How do I pass both the json and base64 correctly to `multiPartContent`?
2. Is there any way to set the headers of the `multiPartContent` so it would sastifsy the template?
3. How do I see the body of the request which is about to be sent? (with all the headers).

Comment: Somebody please edit it, to show the picture

Comment: Please help! The question hasn't been resolved yet

Comment: You could attempt debugging and printing some info?

req.entity =  multipartRequestEntity.build()

 response.success = { resp, data ->
        // response text
        println data.getText()
    }